# Symfony Form Collection - how to get entity id?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have a ShopCategoryCollectionType that only stores ShopCategoryType as collection.

I need to get access to id of single ShopCategory to generate edit path for entity.

I have created custom widget for displaying ShopCategoryWidget

```
        {{ dump(form.vars.data) }}
```

returns:

```
ShopCategory {#7325 ▼
  -id: 13
  -name: "items items"
  -slug: "items-items"
  -status: 1
  -products: PersistentCollection {#7445 ▶}
  -position: 0
}
```

but when i try to get access to attribute of entity

```
{{ dump(form.vars.data.anyAttribute) }}
```

I got:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable.
```

How can I get id attribute of ShopCategory entity?

---

edit:

I have found a issue why it happens.

1. I put a data to ShopCategoryCollectionType

   ```
    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
       $data = [
           'categories' => $this->categoryRepository->findAll()
       ];

       $event->setData($data);
     }
   ```
2. But when i try to receive the data:

   ```
   class ShopCategoryType extends AbstractType {

       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       {
            $builder
           /** fields */
           ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $formEvent) {
           dump($formEvent->getData());
       });
   }
   ```
3. Result is:

   ```
   In ShopCategoryType.php line 30:
       null
    In ShopCategoryType.php line 30:
       ShopCategory {#7574 ▼
       -id: 20
    In ShopCategoryType.php line 30:
       ShopCategory {#7575 ▼
       -id: 21
    In ShopCategoryType.php line 30:
       ShopCategory {#7576 ▼
       -id: 22

   /** and rest of objects */
   }
   ```

Why do I got null at first dump?

Comment: For everyone interested: The first null comes from the prototype of the collection, since there aren't any values set in the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current data in `twig` of your form via `form.vars.value`

```
form.vars.value.{fieldName}
```

For example:

```
form.vars.value.name
```

You can show all field name follow:

```
dump(form.vars.value)
```

Comment: You're basically right, but i have found a issue. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this `ShopCategoryCollectionType` inside your main `FormType`, and `{{ form }}` points into this `FormType`:

> FormType >> ShopCategoryCollectionType >> ShopCategoryType

, access collection's entries using:

```
{{dump(form.children.shopCategories.vars.value[0].id)}}
```

Where, 0, indicates first ShopCategory